# How do you remove or change the functionality of the Publish button on a custom WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type and need keep the post status from getting set to 'Published' when you click the Publish button. Instead, it should work like the Save Draft button. So I either need to figure out how to just remove the Publish button so the user's can only click Save Draft our preferably, update the Publish button functionality so it doesn't set the post to publish.

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PhoenixWing156 was close but one little change so the the other post types get updated as usual.

```
function dont_publish( $data , $postarr ) {  
  if($data['post_type'] == 'custom_post_type') {
    $data['post_status'] = 'draft';   
  }
  return $data;   
}  

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'dont_publish' , '99', 2);
```

Comment: Nice, just wondering how to get values of metaboxes inside a function like this. Like if a custom meta is empty, don't publish. `$postarr` gives me just title, excerpt and so on..

Answer (score 3):

You can use wordpress action hooks to modify default behaviors.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

In your case, you want to use the 'publish_post' hook.

So you can do

```
function dont_publish( $post_ID )  
{
     if(get_post_type($post_ID) == 'your_custom_type'){
         exit;
     }
}
//the dont_publish function will be called after the publish button is clicked
add_action( 'publish_post', 'dont_publish' );
```

The way it is above, nothing will happen at all if the publish button is clicked, but you can play around with the dont_publish function to get the results you want.

Comment: Doesn't appear the publish_post hook runs. Tried to add a `die()` to see if it was even getting called and looks like it's not. Took a look at the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) and the documentation has been deleted for that hook. It it still used?

Comment: Also tried outputting a string in the function before the post type check and still nothing.

Comment: can you try changing the hook name to publish_{post_type_name}?

Comment: Another option is to modify the permissions for who can publish posts.  See: http://wordpress.kdari.net/2012/03/custom-permissions-for-a-custom-post-type.html

Comment: Bingo, publish_{post_type_name} did it! Thanks

Comment: Well... close, but no cigar. At that point it's already been updated to publish and also directs back to the posts list.

Comment: Wondering if there's better solution as this is terrible in terms of user experience.

Answer (score 1):

The wp_insert_post_data hook is called before information about a post is saved to the database.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data
You can try:

```
function dont_publish( $data , $postarr )  
{  
  if($data['post_type'] == 'custom_post_type'){
      $data['post_status'] = 'draft';  
      return $data;
  }     
}  

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'dont_publish' , '99', 2);
```

Comment: close, but no cigar. tried that and appears it works on existing posts, however when I try to create a new and hit publish, it gives e the user doesn't have the permission error. Also, when i go to new post, many of the meta boxes are missing (probably same issue as permission error). Perhaps I'm support to return data regardless of the post type?

Comment: Nevermind, user error :/ That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

*WordPress provides the remove_meta_box() function exactly for this purpose.Just add this below code:-*

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'Your_custom_post_type', 'side' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable the default saving metabox and add you own.

This is not documented well in the developer docs of wordpress.

To do this you have to hook into the "add_meta_boxes"-hook and in the hooked function yo have to call remove_meta_box('submitdiv','your-cpt','side');
The code should be something like this:

```
function your_cpt_metaboxes(){
    remove_meta_box('submitdiv','your-cpt','side');
     ...
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes','function your_cpt_metaboxes');
```

your-cpt has to be changed to the name of your cpt of course.

I was also searching for this handy snippet and found it in the plugin  [Awesome Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-support/).

The original saving metabox code can be found in /wp-admin/includes/metaboxes.php .
Just search for post_submit_meta_box (in WP 5.4 on line 22).